# Vuetify v-stepper not using 100% width and not removing the elevation

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'd like to use the `v-stepper` component to make a progress bar on top of the screen and I'd copy the same content along the multi-screens that made the flow. I am using the sample from the [Vuetify documentation](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-stepper/#props).

Issues:

1. Even I setting the property `elevation="0"` the component keeps elevated and seems to be over a card.
2. The component doesn't use 100% of the width available, it looks to be shrunken.
3. The labels aren't shown.

```
    <template>
        <div style="position: relative">
            <div>
                <v-stepper elevation="0" alt-labels>
                    <v-stepper-header>
                        <v-stepper-step step="1">
                            Ad unit details
                        </v-stepper-step>
    
                        <v-divider></v-divider>
    
                        <v-stepper-step step="2">
                            Ad sizes
                        </v-stepper-step>
    
                        <v-divider></v-divider>
    
                        <v-stepper-step step="3">
                            Ad templates
                        </v-stepper-step>
    
                        <v-divider></v-divider>
    
                        <v-stepper-step step="4">
                            Ad templates
                        </v-stepper-step>
                    </v-stepper-header>
                </v-stepper>
            </div>
        </div>
   </template>
```

Current behavior:

[image]

Comment: None of your issues appear reproducible with just the given code as seen in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/wvRydJX).  Please provide enough minimal code capable of reproducing the issues described.